# SQL - Count the occurence of one column value in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, window-functions

I have a table as shown below. Record key is unique per row

```
ID    RECORD_KEY CONCAT_REJECT    CONCAT_SUB
1     A34785      A123             23
1     B23845      R384             A123
1     H38959      Y345             A123
```

**Expected Result**

```
ID    CONCAT_REJECT    COUNT_REJECT_IN_SUB
1     A123             2
1     R384             0
1     Y345             0
```

How do I perform this count? I tried using `COUNT(CONCAT_REJECT) over (PARTITION BY CONCAT_SUB)`. But it's not giving the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count `concat_sub` in the inner query and then do a left join with `concat_reject` to get final result. Here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9a094/2).

```
select
    id,
    concat_reject,
    coalesce(total, 0) as count_reject_in_sub
from myTable m
left join(
  select
      concat_sub,
      count(*) as total
  from myTable
  group by
      concat_sub
) m1
on m.concat_reject = m1.concat_sub
```

output:

```
| id  | concat_reject | count_reject_in_sub |
| --- | ------------- | ------------------- |
| 1   | A123          | 2                   |
| 1   | R384          | 0                   |
| 1   | Y345          | 0                   |
```